# Mockito Mocking a return value and verify it

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have this class and wants to create a mock to return and verify the return value "50": 
`QAService.java:`

```
@Path("/QAService")
public class QAService {
@GET()
//@Path("/")
@Produces("text/plain")
public String getServiceInfo() {
    return "50";
}
```

My understanding of mock by defintion is that I can create a fake object of an implementation class and mock functions yet to be developed so I can test the interface.

Still I am creating this test to test mocking without having an interface. How do I verify it?:
`QAServiceTest.java:`

```
public class QAServiceTest {

    @Test
    public void getserviceTest () {

    QAService qasmock = mock(QAService.class);
    when(qasmock.getServiceInfo()).thenReturn("50");
    String expected = "50";
    assertEquals(expected, qasmock.getServiceInfo());
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the compile error says?

Comment: Does your `QAServiceTest` class have a method where that code is?

Comment: " it's not compiling" <-- means you have an error at compile time. Can you paste it? (I mean, apart from the fact that your code cannot compile at all since the test is not in a method)

Comment: Wait, if you have the class and you're trying to test the return value, why are you trying to mock it? Also your QAServiceTest code isn't inside a method, probably why it won't compile.

Comment: just updated and pasted the log. @NickWilson I'm fairly new to mockito. I want to mock the QAService.class and the method and verify the return value.

Comment: "invalid method declaration; return type required"  <-- don't tell me the test code you have pasted is your actual code? If yes, no wonder it does not compile

Comment: A class is supposed to have its code in methods. Not directly in the class.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Junit will only run methods annotated with `@Test`, so add it

```
@Test
public void getserviceTest () {
    QAService qasmock = mock(QAService.class);
    when(qasmock.getServiceInfo()).thenReturn("50");
    String expected = "50";
    assertEquals(expected, qasmock.getServiceInfo());
}
```

Also, you should `verify()` that your mock expectations actually happened.

```
verify(qasmock, times(1)).getServiceInfo();
```

Note that it seems like you want to test `QAService`, but you really aren't doing that here. You are simply testing a mock. That's not the same thing.

Create the `QAService` object yourself and use it.

Comment: An important note about using `when` and `verify` is that the order of execution matters. Follow this order: 1. `when ...`. 2. Call the method, e.g. `qasmock.getServiceInfo()`. 3. `verify...`.

Answer (score 21):

Let's get a couple definitions straight, first:

- A **unit test** is a brief bit of code you write to ensure that the system you've developed is behaving correctly. Unit tests are often created in a framework like `JUnit`, but do not need to be. For example, a unit test would `assertEquals(5, calculator.add(2, 3))`.
- A **mock** is an imitation of a real system, which is often used in unit tests. Mocks are often created in frameworks like `Mockito` or `EasyMock`, but do not need to be. Mocks are a form of "test double"—the general term for code you substitute in place of your actual systems, for testing purposes—and Martin Fowler defines them more exactly in an article called ["Mocks Aren't Stubs"](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html).
- When writing a unit test, you're trying to test a single unit, which is often called the **system under test** or **SUT** for short. Each test will probably have a different system under test, and the point is that the code that you are testing in the test is your *real, actual code*, not any sort of mock or fake implementation.
- In a complex application, your classes will probably need to collaborate with other classes that may or may not be written or tested, which are categorically known as **dependencies**. Any given class or system may have its own dependencies, and may be a dependency for other systems. Mocking frameworks are good for mocking those dependencies, not for mocking the system under test.

---

For your example, QAService is the main class you're writing (system under test), and QAServiceTest is the unit test for that system. *No mocks are necessarily required.*

Let's say that QAService depends on another class not yet written, called "StorageService". You don't necessarily want to wait for StorageService to work before writing QAService's tests, so instead of using a real StorageService you use a *mock*. Again, in the *unit test* called QAServiceTest, you use a *real* QAService and mock its *dependency* StorageService.

Even though you don't have StorageService written, you probably have some expectation about how QAService will use that class. Maybe you know that when you call `storageService.store(qaRecord)`, it should return a numeric ID like `101`. Even without the code working, you can create a Mockito `mockStorageService`, and prepare it like this:

```
when(mockStorageService.store(expectedQARecord)).thenReturn(101);
```

Now let's say that at the end of the test, you want to ensure that the method of QAService that you're testing will absolutely call `storageService.delete(101)`. A Mockito `mockStorageService` would check that like this:

```
verify(mockStorageService).delete(101);
```

It is often unnecessary to verify statements you have made with `when`, because the test is unlikely to succeed unless the system under test calls the mock correctly to get that return value (101 here).

Now let's say that you've written another block of code called QAApplication, which you're testing in a unit test called QAApplicationTest, that depends on QAService. You may not have QAService finished or tested, and using a real QAService would require a StorageService, so instead you use *mock* QAService with a *real* QAApplication in your *unit test* called QAApplicationTest.

---

**So, to sum up,** a mock works *within* unit tests to mock the *dependencies* of the *system under test*. In your situation, QAServiceTest will not need a mock QAService, but may be used to mock the dependencies of QAService. If you do need a mock QAService, you'll need it when testing another class where QAService itself is a dependency.

Comment: @Jeff Bowman thanks for a great explanation. I'm aware that it's common to mock an implementation class through an interface. But what if I want to mock a not yet implemented method of a class withouth mocking through an interface? Do I add an empty method to the class `QAService` and mock and stub the expected logic of that method in my `QAServiceTest`?

Comment: @Justin How you add a method is up to you and your development team, including how you agree on interface changes, how you run source control, and what your release cycle is. I would add an empty, documented method to QAService, write a test in QAServiceTest to help me know when the future implementation works, and mock/stub the expected behavior wherever I mock QAService (which is almost definitely not within QAServiceTest).